# looping inside an array using for each

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

I'm working on a wp-query using php.

first I need to get an array of posts ID, using this

```
$artists_ID_array = get_field("page_artiste");
```

(I'm using Advanced Custom Fields with relationship, anyway it doesn't matter... I get an array of values)

here is what the array looks like :

Array ( [0] => 141 [1] => 59 )

then comes my args :

```
$videos = get_posts(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'videos',
        'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),

            'meta_query' => array(

            array(
                'key' => 'page_artiste',
                'value' => $artists_ID_array[0],
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'page_artiste',
                'value' => $artists_ID_array[1],
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'page_artiste',
                'value' => $artists_ID_array[2],
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'page_artiste',
                'value' => $artists_ID_array[3],
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'page_artiste',
                'value' => $artists_ID_array[4],
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
```

and so on... in my meta query, I'm using all the arrays results.

It works fine, I'm getting the posts I want.

But as you can imagine what I'm trying to do is to use for each to avoid having all thoses arrays inside my args "$artists_ID_array[4]", and looping inside my array.

so here is what I've tried, but it's not working... and I can't understand why...

```
<?php 

$artists_ID_array = get_field("page_artiste");

$videos = array(
        'post_type' => 'videos',
        'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
            'meta_query' => array(

    )
);

foreach($artists_ID_array as $value) {
    array_push($videos['meta_query'], array(
                'key' => 'page_artiste',
                'value' => $value,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ));

}

?>
```

can anybody help me with this ?
hope you understand my request

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can simplify this even further, since the meta_query compare allows you to use the value "IN"

"IN" (instead of like) allows you to search the values for any of the values in a given array.

So your get_posts could look something like this:

```
$videos = get_posts(
  array(
    'post_type' => 'videos',
    'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),

     'meta_query' => array(

        array(
            'key' => 'page_artiste',
            'value' => $artists_ID_array,
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
     )
   )
 );
```